# Umbraco 7.1.9 Creating Data Type

Tags: types, umbraco, propertyeditor

I've managed to create multiple custom property editors through app_plugins when I've created a certain website.
All of the existing app_plugins were uploaded at once when I uploaded the entire umbraco website. Everything fine!

Now, a few weeks later, I needed to create a new data type for the website, again with a custom property editor.
On my local machine everything works fine. However, when I upload the folder with the content of my propery editor (manifest, controller, view) to the app_plugins folder , the property editor is not available for use in the list of datatypes.

Any help?

With regards

Roy Decaestecker

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you tried a full restart of the IIS? The manifest file is only read during website startup if I recall correctly

Comment: Tx very much. I've recycled the app pool (restarted worker processes) on in the control panel of my hostingplatform.

Comment: Try to delete all files in /app_data/TEMP/ClientDependency and /app_data/TEMP/PluginCache

Comment: I've posted comment as an answer instead of a comment, if anyone else should have the same problem in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Recycle the app pool. The manifest file is only read during startup